# Formula Field to create custom view

Tags: salesforce, formula, apex

I have the scenario like the Case Contact is the user that created the case.
I want to create the List view where the current logon user equals to Case Contact.

I have added created formula field(CreatedBy$User) on Case object.

```
IF(!ISBLANK(ContactId), IF($User.ContactId == ContactId , "TRUE", "FALSE"), "FALSE")
```

now in the List view i have added filter:

```
CreatedBy$User equals TRUE
```

but it is not showing me the Cases of current logon user.

Can anyone can suggest what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The contactId will be populated in the User object if the UserType ( LicenseType on older Api version) is Portal User or any kind of the Portal Licenses.

[User-ContactId](http://chavastol.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-usercontactid-and-contactuser.html)

Are your users portal users? If not, then you could probably just use `$User.Id`